# Navigating python traceback from source file buffer

Tags: python, debugging, emacs

I'm using the current python-mode to edit my source file in top window and a python inferior shell in bottom window to see the outputs (using `C-c C-c` from the source file, the cursor stays in the top, source file window).

Is there a way to navigate the traceback errors while still staying in the source code window? 
Also - is there a similar way to navigate errors just in the file that was actually sent (i.e. not those errors coming from called external files)?

At the moment I either do `M-g M-g` to jump to line number, or switch to the python shell window and navigate there to the error I want to have a look at.

This would be a tremendous efficiency boost!
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there are the functions [next/previous]-error bound `M-g M-n` and `M-g M-p` that do this (for some reason unmentioned in the python mode descriptions...). I'll keep the question open if somebody has a good solution to the second part - cycle only through the errors in the current file.

Answer (score 0):

[realgud](https://github.com/realgud/realgud) that I wrote has a command (and mode) for shells called `realgud-track-mode`. When you invoke that, the debugger you are using will be prompted. For example it could be `pdb` (but I prefer `trepan3k` since I wrote that too)

At any rate once all of this is set up, then the command `realgud:goto-lang-backtrace-line` which is bound to  `C-c ! !` will parse the line in the shell window and bring the file at the location mentioned up in another buffer.